# Google Login Provider can not enable Authentication on firebase "Error updating Google"

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I have one problem about firebase on Web
I tried to enable authentication for Google in firebase

It's japanese,
that means "Error updating Google"

How can i resolve this problem?
Actually I have no idea...

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: I have the same error, nothing helps :(

Comment: Finally worked for me costly but efficient solution - delete Firebase project and recreate it.. http://www.churyumov.com/2021/06/how-to-implement-sign-in-via-google.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also go directly to Google Cloud Platform console https://console.cloud.google.com/  and go to Identity Platform section. Firebase is interface to Identity Platform in GCP. Over there you'll see more explicit information.

Comment: Thanks you. I got a error for firebase internal :
"google.internal.firebase.v1.FirebaseInternalProductService.EnableGoogleSignIn"

so I just remake my project and resolve it, Thanks

Comment: I did this and it worked for me. The Google Cloud Console Identity Platform product allowed me to continue where the Firebase UI was broken.

When I added the Identity Platform, it asked me if I was sure I wanted to upgrade. I said yes.

Then I was able to add Google Sign-In as a provider and set the web client ID and secret (there's a tooltip that links you to where you can find it).

Once I fixed Google Sign-In via the Google Cloud Console, when I refreshed my Firebase Console, Google Sign-In showed up as expected.

Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score -1):

In case someone else runs into `google.internal.firebase.v1.FirebaseInternalProductService.EnableGoogleSignIn`

You must enable Google Sign in before starting to auth users. You can find this switch inside the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/):

1. Open the Auth section.
2. On the Sign in method tab, enable the Google sign-in method
3. click Save

For more information regarding authentication using Google Sign-in for web here's this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#before_you_begin)